# The last ten JIRAs I have worked on

Tags: jira

Is there anyway to find the last 10 JIRAs I have worked on - irrespective of time period?  By worked on, I mean any thing I have updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could query the activity stream.

For example here are my last (up to) 10 issues on jira.atlassian.com in ATOM format:

https://jira.atlassian.com/activity?provider=jira&maxResults=10&streams=user+IS+david@davidsimpson.me

If you want authenticated, try appending parameters `&os_username=a.n.other&os_password=abc123` (or similar) to the URL.

Incidentally, an activity stream similar to this is present in your JIRA profile, e.g. https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=david%40davidsimpson.me